# nextChar() in java

Tags: java, char, java.util.scanner

If I'm taking input with a scanner and I want to put a single character into a char type variable, what is the most efficient algorithm? I just noticed that both next() and nextLine() return strings regardless of the size, and aside from getting a string, casting it into a char array and then taking the first element, I can't think of how I would do this. There must be a more efficient way!

Comment: Why do you think getting a String input is inefficient?  What do you think is slower or less efficient, Java's getting in a String and extracting a char or the user's typing in a char or chars?

Comment: Java char-type variables aren't big enough to hold a character.

Comment: Java char-type's are 16bit wide! What encoding are you using that a primitive type would have to work for!  Unicode will work for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `FileChannel` to create a `ByteBuffer`.  Once here you can then call the `asCharBuffer()` method to return a char buffer.

Here's a decent example: 
[Example using CharBuffers](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/SaveandreadtextusingFileChannelwithCharBuffer.htm)

Comment: this would only be useful if the characters were utf16 encoded.  that's not a general purpose byte to char conversion utility.

Comment: @jtahlborn java.lang.String(byte[] buf, String encoding) ?

Answer (score 3):

To read a character from input you can use the builtin function `char charAt()`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
char c = sc.next().charAt(0)
```

Comment: What's `sc`'s type?